# elixir installed but iex command error

Tags: elixir

I have installed Elixir in my mac through homebrew, but when I try to run iex, it report error:

> iex
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/elixir/1.1.1/bin/elixir: line 109: exec: erl: not found

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you are simply missing Erlang, which Elixir requires.

You can find more information in the Elixir documentation to learn how to install Erlang on OS X: http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#installing-erlang

The Riak documentation is also helpful: https://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/#Mac-OS-X-Prerequisites

Good luck!

Comment: Do you have ERL_PATH defined in your environment? You can check with `env | grep ERL_PATH`

Comment: I configured ERL_PATH then it works, thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Erlang is missing but default installation through homebrew should install all required files(I installed the same way and all dependencies where automatically installed). 
It seems to me that mac is unable to find path to erlang, try reinstalling if it helps.
Try typing `erl` on console/terminal and see if it opens erlang